# Nagios bash syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to refer with this question to the following post where I got the Skript:
[Post with Script](https://serverfault.com/questions/309913/how-i-can-check-for-exact-amount-of-space-mb-or-gb-in-nagios-using-check-nt-co)

I'm using Bash 4.1.2(1) and when I try to execute the script, I get following error messages:

```
 ./check_disk_by_size.sh: Zeile 9: [: ==: Einstelliger (unärer) Operator erwartet.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./check_disk_by_size.sh: Zeile 13: [: -eq: Einstelliger (unärer) Operator erwartet.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./check_disk_by_size.sh: Zeile 16: [: Zu viele Argumente.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./check_disk_by_size.sh: Zeile 19: [: -eq: Einstelliger (unärer) Operator erwartet.
```

I have basic Bash-scripting experiences but whenever I change something, I get even more errors. I'm not able to bring it to work.

EDIT 1: Here's the script

```
#!/bin/bash

FREESPACE=`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $2 -p 12489 -s PASSWORD \
-v USEDDISKSPACE -l $4 | awk -F"- " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F "|" '{ print $1 }'`

SIZE=`echo $FREESPACE | awk '{ print $2 }'`
UNIT=`echo $FREESPACE | awk '{ print $3 }'`

if [ $UNIT == "Gb" ]; then
    SIZE=`echo $SIZE \* 1024 | bc`
fi

if [ `echo "$SIZE >= $6" | bc` -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$4:\_Drive_Space OK - $FREESPACE"
    exit 0
elif [ `echo "$SIZE < $6" | bc` -eq 1 -a `echo "$SIZE > $8" | bc` -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$4:\_Drive_Space WARNING - $FREESPACE"
    exit 1
elif [ `echo "$SIZE <= $8" | bc` -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$4:\_Drive_Space CRITICAL - $FREESPACE"
    exit 2
fi
```

I run the script like this:

```
./check_disk_by_size -H [IP_Adress] -l [DRIVE] -w [INTEGER] -c [INTEGER] -p [PORT] -s [PASSWORD]
```

Example:

```
./check_disk_by_size -H 192.168.1.110 -l c -w 10240 -c 8192 -p 12489 -s PASSWORD
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your help!
It works now :) The script looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

FREESPACE=`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $2 -p 12489 -s Nag4AlphA \
-v USEDDISKSPACE -l $4 | awk -F"- " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F "|" '{ print $1 }'`

SIZE=`echo $FREESPACE | awk '{ print $2 }'`
UNIT=`echo $FREESPACE | awk '{ print $3 }'`

if [ "$UNIT" == "Gb" ]; then
    SIZE="$(echo "$(($SIZE * 1024))" | bc)"
fi


echo $SIZE
echo " " 
echo $6
echo " "
echo $8

if [ $SIZE -ge $6 ]; then
    echo "$4:\_Drive_Space OK - $FREESPACE"
    exit 0
elif [ $SIZE -lt $6 -a $SIZE -gt $8 ]; then
    echo "$4:\_Drive_Space WARNING - $FREESPACE"
    exit 1
elif [ $SIZE -lt $8 ]; then
    echo "$4:\_Drive_Space CRITICAL - $FREESPACE"
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: Are you using `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` in your script?

Comment: Seems somewhere in your script you are trying to compare values with different types (e.g String vs Intgeger). Hard to say while we cannot see your script and without knowing what it is supposed to do...

Comment: Thanks for the replies!
I edited the post with the script.

Comment: What's in your FREESPACE variable? Execute it manually or echo it before you get the SIZE and UNIT out of it.
There is also another version of the script in the thread you posted.

Comment: Try to run your script with `bash -x check_disk_by_size arguments` so you can have a small debug on how it is performing.

Comment: Please repost the error messages with the LC_LANG setting set to 'C' or en_US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it looks like the left operand in the "if test" is empty.

About **why** there might be an empty value, I suggest you to run the Nagios command from the shell and see what it does. What's its output?
Run all the steps to the output:

1. `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $2 -p 12489 -s PASSWORD -v USEDDISKSPACE -l $4`
2. `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $2 -p 12489 -s PASSWORD
   -v USEDDISKSPACE -l $4 | awk -F"- " '{ print $4 }'`
3. `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H $2 -p 12489 -s PASSWORD
   -v USEDDISKSPACE -l $4 | awk -F"- " '{ print $4 }' | awk -F "|" '{ print $1 }'`

About the script itself I "kindly suggest" to:

- **ALWAYS** enclose variables in double quotes, **EVERYWHERE**
- **ALWAYS** prefer `$()` instead of the backticks for shell expansion, **EVERYWHERE**
- **ALWAYS** enclose shell expansion in double quotes, **EVERYWHERE**

Of course seldom exceptions do apply, like when you test numeric values.

I don't mean to be rude, just make sure you understand how important this is :)

Orignal:

```
if [ $UNIT == "Gb" ]; then
    SIZE=`echo $SIZE \* 1024 | bc`
fi
```

Hardened:

```
if [ "$UNIT" == "Gb" ]; then
    SIZE="$(echo "$SIZE * 1024" | bc)"
fi
```

I never ever had any problem after I started to consistently follow these rules.

Here is a nice article about Bash scripting best practices: http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts/ and another one about shell expansion http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

**UDPATE:** corrected few typos

Comment: Interesting articles for reading (and learning) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now and I also learned something :)